# Pythagorean triplet and extention

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Could your help me in my two questions please...

1. What integer Pythagorean triple results from Diophantine solution to the problem of dividing a given square into two squares?
2. How to prove that Fermat's last theorem is true for all exponents of n, if its is true for
   n = 4 and all odd primes of n?

These are the problems, which need serious discussion...
Thanking you,
Kish

Comment: These two questions are very different, and could do with being separated. I don't understand what you are trying to ask in the first one. Are you looking for nearly isosceles right angled triangles with integer sides?

Comment: @yes these two question are different.

Comment: Mark Bennet!The first question can be read as follows:

Comment: @MarkBennet What integer Pythagoren Triple results from Diophantine Solution to the problem of dividing a given square into two squares?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by Diophantine Solution in this context - all pythagorean triples satisfy $a^2+b^2=c^2$